# bash + awk : looping over an array of 4 elements that returns size of 1?

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, awk

I have the following script which uses awk to match fields with user input

```
NB=$#
FILE=myfile

#GET INPUT
if [ $NB -eq 1 ]
then
    A=`awk -F "\t" -v town="$1" 'tolower($3) ~ tolower(town) {print NR}' $FILE`
fi
```

If I print the output, it reads :

```
7188 24369 77205 101441
```

Which is what I expected. Then if I do the following:

```
IFS=' '
array=($A)
echo ${#array[@]}
```

I actually get a length of 1 (?). Furthermore, if I try:

```
for x in $array
do
    echo $x
done
```

It actually prints out :

```
7188
24369
77205
101441
```

How can I have it return the length of 4. I don't understand how the `for...in` works if there's only 1 element?

EDIT :

echo `$A | od -c` before I create the array is:

```
0000000   7   1   8   8       2   4   3   6   9       7   7   2   0   5
0000020       1   0   1   4   4   1  \n
0000030
```

echo `$A | od -c` after I create the array is:

```
0000000   7   1   8   8  \n   2   4   3   6   9  \n   7   7   2   0   5
0000020  \n   1   0   1   4   4   1  \n
0000030
```

Comment: Is there a reason you set `IFS=' '`? The default value should have worked for you, as it already includes the newline character.

Comment: I think I was using different code to render from awk to an array. But you're right, it seems to work now...sigh. I thought I had spaces between my values, so I wanted to be 100% the delimiter was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because returned output from awk is newline (`\n`) delimited instead of space delimited. So if you have IFS like this instead:

```
IFS=$'\n' # newline between quotes
```

Then it will echo `array length = 4` as you are expecting.

Comment: I edited it, and still echoes 1. Also, how could the loop print out 4 elements if the length is still just 1? I also tried using `tr` to form my array (something like `array=( $(echo $A | tr " " "\n") )`) with no luck.

Comment: First thing is that you need to run a loop to traverse array like this: `for x in ${array[@]}` not like what you wrote. Second thing can you show output of `echo $A | od -c` ?

Comment: sure! Added the output to the question itself (for formatting).

Comment: Looks like you have `\n` in your string `$A`. Can you try `IFS=$'\n'`